# React Form to send data to PHP script which should then send email

Tags: php, reactjs, lamp

I have been struggling with this one quite a bit... Some background - my React front end is running on a LAMP back end (company's set up not my choice) and I currently have the task of creating a contact form that when submitted - will send the form data to a PHP script which should then trigger an email to be sent to a specific inbox we have set up.

I feel as though I understand the form portion correct as I am most comfortable with HTML/CSS/JS/React, but the LAMP stack set up is really throwing me. I'll try to list specific questions clearly below.

1. How would one directly target a file on an EC2 instance?

I am currently getting a 500 error (failed to load resource) from the server when attempting to target my PHP file. I have tried an absolute path from the root of the server as well as a path from the root directory of the project. Either way it fails.

2. I am getting a React warning in console "Form Submission failed because form is not connected", but to my knowledge the form is connected... The action attribute is tied to the PHP file that I would like to send data to.

Currently I have an async await call running when the form is submitted which is supposed to make a fetch/POST call to the file and then things should be handled, but again I am having the issues listed above.

I do not want to share publicly share code because this is a company project, but if someone has experience with this type of set up and has time to help someone trouble shoot please let me know. Sorry for the novel folks and thank you for any help!

Edit - is there any type of work around I could use to avoid even sending this to PHP script and generating an email an alternative way besides emailJS?

Comment: A 500 error is a server side error. Check your error logs.

Comment: `if someone has experience with this type of set up and has time to help someone trouble shoot please let me know`...that's not how this site works, sorry. The purpose of this site is to create repository of useful, interesting and widely applicable programming questions for the benefit of future readers. Doing (potentially length) bespoke troubleshooting on code which isn't published here doesn't help us achieve that goal. That's something you could hire a freelance developer for. But as mentioned above, you should check your PHP error log file first before doing anything else.

Comment: P.S. As you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) 
I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: `I do not want to share publicly share code because this is a company project`...realistically it's unlikely that a little script to send an email is going to give away any trade secrets...especially if it isn't even working correctly. A contact form is hardly a USP, you can find demos and working source code for such things in dozens of places online.

Comment: `is there any type of work around I could use to avoid even sending this to PHP script`...you need some sort of server-side code in order to send an email. It can't be done directly from the browser. So either you use PHP or you use another server-side language.

Comment: Hello - Thank you so much for the detailed response and guidance on the How To... My apologies for not following the normal protocol. As you noticed... Long time lurker - new user here. I will look into the error logs and see what I can make of that. Really appreciate your response and guidance. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a standard html form then the presumably you have `action` and `method` attributes on the form.

You would traditionally:

1. Set the form `action` attribute to point at your php script. There should be no reason the php script isn't directly accessible unless it's off document root or you have a .htaccess file that is routing all requests through an intermediary (like an index.php file).
2. Set the form `method` attribute to `POST`.
3. The PHP script directed to in the action should read from $_POST which is an array that will contain any data sent via POST request to your php script.
4. You can then use a variety of methods for sending the email. Since you've mentioned EC2 you're obviously in AWS. In this case AWS offer a great email service called Simple Email Service. You can find the SDK and example scripts for sending an email via it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html
   However, do note that SES requires you to go through a verification process as you will initially be in a sandbox mode that has certain restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and outline! 

We do have an htaccess that routes to our "serve.php" file which is synonymous with the index.php file you speak of. This is what serves up our website and I think this is where my disconnect is occurring, but I'm also no quite sure how to remedy that, but thank you for honing in on what is occurring/making me more confident that I need to figure out what to do with those files in order to allow the call to go through.

Comment: Are you using a framework? If you cannot route directly to your PHP file then perhaps you have a routes.php or something of that nature that would permit you to create a basic endpoint. You could then post your data to that.

Comment: I know I can create an endpoint using my serve.php file (our index.php) because that currently handles our public web traffic. 

This actually controls our private portal which is entirely separate as well as our public portal so they're kinda wrapped into one. 

If I understand you correctly - create an endpoint - allow the .php script to be located there - post the data to that end point which activates the script?

Comment: Yes that's about the size of it. Basically you just need a POST route/endpoint created that invokes whatever class/method that houses your code for sending emails.  If you have an actual endpoint then you could even send this data via fetch from the React frontend and never reload the page. But sounds like you have the React part down.